# Programming Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a bit `i` that is sent over a noisy channel from source to sink. The probability of `i` bein a `1` at the source is Pr(S_1). The probability of `i` being a `0` at the source is Pr(S_0).

Similarily, the probability of `i` being a `1` at the sink is Pr(D_1) and being a `0` at the sink is Pr(D_0).

I want to calculate the conditional probiability of sending a `1` and receiving a `0`, i.e.: `Pr(D_0|S_1)`.

Is it the write way to compute it as:
`Pr(D_0|S_1)= (Pr(D_0) + Pr(S_1)) / Pr(S_1)`?

Comment: Note:  your formula does not define a probability (it simplifies to $1+\frac {P(D_0)}{P(S_1)}$ which is greater than $1$ (assuming each probability is non-zero). More generally, your data is not enough to allow you to compute the conditional probability.  I outline some examples in my post below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you want is not determined by the data you provide.  For example, suppose the source probabilities were both $\frac 12$.  Then, consider three scenarios:

Scenario A:  Your transmitter is perfect.  Then the two sink probabilities are also both $\frac 12$ and the conditional probability of receiving a $0$ when a $1$ was transmitted is $0$.

Scenario B: your transmitter is perfectly wrong (it always sends the wrong thing).  then again the two sink probabilities are both $\frac 12$ but now the conditional probability of receiving a $0$ when a $1$ was transmitted is $1$.

Scenario C:  your transmitter is random (it sends $1,0$ with probability $\frac 12$ without regard to what was transmitted).  In this case the conditional probability of receiving a $0$ when a $1$ was transmitted is $\frac 12$.